# How to pass a class as an argument to another classes constructor?

Tags: c++

The problem i get is inside Person.cpp , in the constructor.When i do this ,everything works ok

```
Person::Person(string n,Birthday b)
:    name(n) ,
    birthday(b)
{}
```

when i do this , i get errors...

```
Person::Person(string n,Birthday b) {
    name = n;
    birthday = b;
}
```

my question is how to pass a class as an argument to another classes constructor?

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Birthday.h"
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Birthday birth(13,4,1996);

    Person bill("Billy Par",birth);
    bill.printInfo();
    return 0;
}
```

Person.cpp :

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Person::Person(string n,Birthday b)
:    name(n) ,
    birthday(b)
{}

void Person::printInfo() {
    cout << name << " was born on ";
    birthday.printDate();
}
```

Birthday.cpp:

```
#include "Birthday.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Birthday::Birthday(int d,int m,int y) {
    day = d;
    month = m;
    year = y;
}

void Birthday::printDate() {
    cout << day << "/" << month << "/" << year << endl;
}
```

Person.h:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <string>
#include "Birthday.h"

using namespace std;

class Person {
public:
    Person(string n,Birthday b);
    void printInfo();
private:
    string name;
    Birthday birthday;
};

#endif // PERSON_H
```

Birthday.h:

```
#ifndef BIRTHDAY_H
#define BIRTHDAY_H

class Birthday {
public:
    Birthday(int d,int m,int y);
    void printDate();
private:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

#endif // BIRTHDAY_H
```

Comment: "When i do this ,everything works ok" Do it this way then?

Comment: Birthday doesn't have default constructor. What's the actual question?

Comment: @orhtej2, no, wrong duplicate.

Comment: Works fine here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93f443e25366297d

Comment: @SergeyA thank you , all it needed was a Birthday(){} default constructor...

Comment: Jas, you were probably better off using the member initializer list and copy constructor than the assignment.

Comment: when you use the initializer list it works, then just stop there. There is no good reason not to use the initializer list when you can

Comment: ***when i do this , i get errors...*** Always add your errors to your question as text. if this is Visual Studio get the text from the Output Tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

When you enter the body of the constructor all member objects must have already been constructed.

```
Person::Person(string n,Birthday b) 
{ // birthday must be constructed before here
    name = n;
    birthday = b; // this is an assignment, not an initialization
}
```

In the absence of the member being initialized in the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) as was done in the question with

```
Person::Person(string n,Birthday b)
:    name(n) ,
    birthday(b)
{}
```

using `Birthday`'s [automatically-generated copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor), the default constructor will be used. `Birthday` has no default constructor (the compiler will not create a default constructor if you have a user defined constructor), so the compiler emits an error and produces no usable object.

## Options (other than, like, rage-quitting or something)

1) Pass in a `Birthday` and copy it as above.

Side notes: You can avoid the redundant `Birthday` object hanging around. 
If building to a recent C++ standard you can

```
Person bill("Billy Par", {13,4,1996});
```

and If you don't have at least C++11 support you can

```
Person bill("Billy Par",Birthday(13,4,1996));
```

This creates a temporary `Birthday` that lives to the end of the line. A good compiler knows tricks to optimize the smurf out of this, so you might never even know the temporary was there at all.

Passing by `const` reference

```
Person::Person(string n,const Birthday &b)
:    name(n) ,
    birthday(b)
{}
```

has the potential to be slightly better by eliminating a copy, but modern compilers know this trick, too.

2) Add additional parameters to `Person`'s constructor and use them to invoke Birthday's constructor in the member initializer list.

```
Person::Person(string n, int d, int m, int y)
:    name(n) ,
    birthday(d,m,y)
{}
```

Personal opinion, I find

```
Person bill("Billy Par",Birthday(13,4,1996));
```

to better express intent and be more versatile.

3) Add a default constructor to `Birthday`

I don't really like this option. For simple class like `Birthday` it's not bad, but gives no advantages over option one and makes it more difficult for the compiler to apply several useful optimizations. For a complex or hard-to-construct class, this option goes through the work of default construction and then adds on whatever work is required by assignment.

Side Note: If Modern C++ is available a trivial default constructor is easy. Add

```
Birthday() = default;
```

to the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

All it needed to work , was a default birthday constructor.

Comment: It doesn't need that, at least what you posted doesn't.  The code works just fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93f443e25366297d)

Comment: @NathanOliver you misunderstood the question. When OP uses member initializer list, everything works. It doesn't work when OP is not using one.